# post blob to google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, blob, fetch-api

Iam trying to upload a file to the Google Cloud via JavaScript.
But but right now i'm failing miserably.

This is my Code so far:

```
 function uploadFile(){

    const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let blob;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(file)
        blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], {type: file.type });

        fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/"my_bucket_here"/o', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer "Token here"'
            },
            body: blob,
        })
            .then(response => console.log('Success'))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}
```

1. At first I try to get the Token from my input tag in my html File

   ```
   const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
   ```

**Html:**

```
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" class="box">
```

2. Then I have the reader.onload function where I store the File into a Blob

the logging of the File shows me the selectet File so the Code where i get my File should work....

3. After that Iam trying to Post my Blob via fetch Api to my bucket

I think this is the point where the Code **fails**, because I get an 400 Http Error.

**POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/yaec_example/o 400
reader.onload @ upload.js:11
load (async)
uploadFile @ upload.js:7
onclick @ index.html?_ijt=v0tmlt6ecn7lbgsgmve0d34dra:49**

*It would be great if someone experienced in Google Cloud Upload could help me...*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that in this case, the following curl command in the official document will be useful for understanding this request.

```bash
curl -X POST --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=OBJECT_NAME"
```

In your showing script, how about modifying `uploadFile()` as follows?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `"my_bucket_here"` and `"Token here"` to your actual values.

```js
function uploadFile() {
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    const mimeType = file.type;
    const data = e.target.result;
    fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/"my_bucket_here"/o?uploadType=media&name=samplename', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': mimeType,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer "Token here"'
      },
      body: data,
    })
      .then(response => console.log('Success'))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your access token can be used for uploading the file to this API. Please be careful about this. If an error related to the authorization and the permission, please confirm it again.

#### Reference:

- [Upload objects from a filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> This solution works for me, but now the file isn't uploaded as Blob. Is there any way to transform the data constant into a JavaScript Blob?

If you want to use your blob of `blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], {type: file.type });`, how about the following sample modified script? In this case, `uploadType=multipart` is used as follows.

```bash
curl -X POST --data-binary @MULTIPART_FILE_LOCATION \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=BOUNDARY_STRING" \
    -H "Content-Length: MULTIPART_FILE_SIZE" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=multipart"
```

#### Modified script:

```js
function uploadFile() {
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], { type: file.type });
    const metadata = { name: "sampleName" };
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
    form.append('file', blob);
    fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/"my_bucket_here"/o?uploadType=multipart', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer "Token here"' },
      body: form,
    })
      .then(response => console.log('Success'))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: Hey Tanaike, thanks for your help! This solution works for me, but now the file isn't uploaded as Blob. Is there any way to transform the data constant into a JavaScript Blob?

Comment: @Lukas.lmst Thank you for replying. From `thanks for your help! This solution works for me`, I understood that my proposed script worked in your test. About `but now the file isn't uploaded as Blob. Is there any way to transform the data constant into a JavaScript Blob?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: @Lukas.lmst In this case, I think that it is not required to convert the data as a blob. I think that you can upload a file with the byte array. For example, if you have a blob and you want to upload it, it is required to convert the blob to the byte array for uploading. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Lukas.lmst About `This solution works for me, but now the file isn't uploaded as Blob. Is there any way to transform the data constant into a JavaScript Blob?`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual goal, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?